# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column - Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, where-clause

I'm using the framework Laravel.

I have 2 tables (Users and Members). When I want to login, I get the error message:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_email' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `members` where `user_email` = ?
>   limit 1) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'test@hotmail.com', ))

Table Users

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `festival_aid`.`users` (
  `user_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_modified` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_deleted` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_lastlogin` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_locked` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_email_UNIQUE` (`user_email` ASC),
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table Members

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `festival_aid`.`members` (
  `member_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_password` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `member_salt` CHAR(22) NOT NULL,
  `member_token` VARCHAR(128) NULL,
  `member_confirmed` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`, `user_id`),
  INDEX `fk_members_users1_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_members_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `festival_aid`.`users` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Migration User

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('user_id');

            $table->string('user_email');
            $table->timestamp('user_created');
            $table->timestamp('user_modified');
            $table->timestamp('user_deleted');
            $table->timestamp('user_lastlogin');
            $table->timestamp('user_locked');
        });
    }
```

Migration Member

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('members', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('member_id');

            $table->string('member_password');
            $table->string('member_salt');
            $table->string('member_token');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users');
            //->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamp('member_confirmed');
        });
    }
```

Model User

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Model Member

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Member extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $table = 'members';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('member_password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->member_password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'member_id';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('User');
    }
}
```

The Member model uses:
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Auth;

interface UserInterface {

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier();

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword();

}
```

Controller

```
public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        $rules = array('user_email' => 'required', 'member_password' => 'required');

        $v = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        if($v->passes())
        {
            $credentials = array('user_email' => $input['user_email'], 'member_password' => $input['member_password']);

            if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
            {
                return Redirect::to('/home');

            } else {

                return Redirect::to('login');
            }

        } else {

            return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($v);
        }
    }
```

auth.php

```
return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Authentication Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the authentication driver that will be utilized.
    | This drivers manages the retrieval and authentication of the users
    | attempting to get access to protected areas of your application.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'eloquent',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
    | Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
    | is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
    |
    */

    'model' => 'Member',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
    | table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
    | default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'members',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reminder Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the settings for password reminders, including a view
    | that should be used as your password reminder e-mail. You will also
    | be able to set the name of the table that holds the reset tokens.
    |
    | The "expire" time is the number of minutes that the reminder should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'reminder' => array(

        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

        'table' => 'password_reminders',

        'expire' => 60,

    ),

);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where's the code relating to Auth::attempt($credentials)?

Comment: Isn't that the code in my Model: Member?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework, but Auth::attempt is a static call to the attempt method of the Auth class, not to Member::something

Comment: The Member model uses this: use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have configured the `auth.php` and used `members` table for authentication but there is no `user_email` field in the `members` table so, Laravel says

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_email' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from members where user_email = ? limit
>   1) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'test@hotmail.com', ))

Because, it tries to match the `user_email` in the `members` table and it's not there. According to your `auth` configuration, `laravel` is using `members` table for authentication not `users` table.

Comment: That's the point ,, you have to look for your validation ( exists[table] ) , you have to be sure that the table which you validate against have the row matched.

Comment: what is mean :-> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''''  in where clause, and where class is :-> WHERE (`' '` = ''''), can i get help @The Alpha

Comment: In that table the mentioned column is not available. @Gem

Comment: Actually i get this error from soap API, how can I update in soap.

Comment: Someone already post in Magento forum, https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/Magento-SOAP-V2-Unknown-column-Error/m-p/113643/highlight/true#M9318

Answer (score 4):

You don't have a field named `user_email` in the members table
... as for why, I'm not sure as the code "looks" like it should try to join on different fields

Does the Auth::attempt method perform a join of the schema?
Run `grep -Rl 'class Auth' /path/to/framework` and find where the `attempt` method is and what it does.

Comment: The user_email field is located in the users table. The Auth::attempt only redirects you to the homepage or back to loginpage.

Comment: No, that is the action that has been specified as a result of a successful (read returns true) call to Auth::attempt. You need to find the code that contains 'class Auth '

Comment: class Auth doesn't exist beyond being a Facade to Laravel's IoC container that has bindings to Authorization methods. `Auth::attempt` uses laravels configuration / extensions (via closures) to build the Auth implementation. Not havinng a `user_email` field in the members table however is spot on. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was also this Problem in laravel version 9 when I created multi-authentication.

I use the Same Table as the User like this:

```
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
```

and my problem is Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change where Member class

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasOne('User');
} 

return $this->belongsTo('User');
```

Comment: This is fixed mine, while I have the same error but confused between belongsTo and hasMany, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Just use this command:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```