# SQL error on password resetting laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to implement a password reset on my Laravel 5.1 app using  the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#resetting-passwords). When i click on send password reset button it gives me the following error.

> QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `password_resets` where `email` = abc@abc.com).

Comment: Do you have `email` column in `passwords_resets` table?

Comment: post the relevant code of your query here..

Comment: [SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column - Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711253/sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-laravel?answertab=votes#tab-top) it will works fine for me.

Comment: yeah,that issue is solved and following error is thrown now. Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383: Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""

Answer (score 1):

[image]Kindly check the password_resets table in your database. And see if email column exists.

Comment: yeah,that issue is solved and following  error is thrown now.    Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""

Comment: Kindly accept this answer if it helped you. And ask the new question on a new thread. Not here. Thanks!