# Additive parameters in factory are added to table insert command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, factory

In my Laravel 5.8 app I create factory with defintion in database/factories/HostelReviewFactory.php :

```
$factory->define(App\HostelReview::class, function (Faker $faker, $parentParams) {
    $flag_status= 'N';
    if( rand(1,4) == 1) {
        $flag_status= 'R';
    }

    $parent_hostel_id= $parentParams['parent_hostel_id'];

    return [

        'hostel_id'             =>  $parent_hostel_id,
        'email_inquiried'       =>  $faker->safeEmail,

        'full_name'             => $faker->name,
        'status'                => 'A',
        'flag_status'           => $flag_status,
        'review'                => $faker->text,
        'stars_rating_type_id'  => rand(1,5),
        'created_at'            => $faker->dateTimeBetween(  '-2 years', 'now', config('app.timezone')  ) ,
    ];
});
```

and running it from seeder database/seeds/HostelReviewsTableSeeder.php :

```
factory(App\HostelReview::class, 10)->create([ 'parent_hostel_id' => 30 ]);
```

I got error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'parent_hostel_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `ad_hostel_reviews` (`hostel_id`, `email_inquiried`, `full_name`, `status`, `flag_status`, `review`, `stars_rating_type_id`, `created_at`, `parent_hostel_id`) values (30, beer.ozella@example.com, Jamel Konopelski, A, N, Quis mollitia voluptas occaecati corrupti ut. Commodi dolorem delectus architecto nesciunt voluptatem quos. Itaque natus adipisci dicta impedit sint. Alias inventore accusantium ea., 3, 2018-02-13 01:18:34, 30))
```

looks like all values from $parentParams are added to fields list of target table, and I do not need it, as $parentParams
are just parameters I want to set to factory. 
What is wrong ?

Comment: Does your table have this column "parent_hostel_id"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[42S22\]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711253/sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your needs correctly,
You want to be able to create HostelReview with a factory that has a relationship with an Hostel

The parameters you pass to factory(App\HostelReview::class, 10)->create([...]) will be handled as specific model properties and overrides the default data in the factory.
What you need is:

- Define a default hostel that will be attached to the review
- Be able to inject a specific Hostel to the review

This is how the HostelReview will look like:

```
$factory->define(App\HostelReview::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $flag_status= 'N';
    if( rand(1,4) == 1) {
        $flag_status= 'R';
    }

    return [

        'hostel_id'             => function () {
            return factory(App\Hostel::class)->create()->id; // This will create a new Hostel and set the id in case you did not express in the caller the hostel_id to inject
        },
        'email_inquiried'       => $faker->safeEmail,
        'full_name'             => $faker->name,
        'status'                => 'A',
        'flag_status'           => $flag_status,
        'review'                => $faker->text,
        'stars_rating_type_id'  => rand(1,5),
        'created_at'            => $faker->dateTimeBetween(  '-2 years', 'now', config('app.timezone')  ) ,
    ];
});
```

For the second point you can override the default attached Hostel with this call:

```
factory(App\HostelReview::class, 10)->create(['hostel_id' => 30]);
```