# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Update_Profile' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `updated_at` = 2021-01-11 00:01:39,

Tags: laravel, eloquent

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Update_Profile' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `updated_at` = 2021-01-11 00:01:39, `Update_Profile` = Update Profile where `id` = 12)

I am getting this error whenever a user tries to update his/her profile.

[This is where the user click the UPDATE PROFILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Lnf.png)

[And this is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51tKQ.png)

[And I think the error is from here but I don't now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GINLI.png)

Can someone help me out please.

Comment: show us your code. However it clearly mention the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[42S22\]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711253/sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

If `update_profile` is available in your table and you got that error probably this will be sloved with one of two ways below:
1 - Run command 'composer dumpautoload' in the terminal
2 - Clear this path contents : \storage\framework\views*